# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem. What is missing?

Tags: java

```
/*
 * Case Based Student Performance Determination System:
 * Designed by Degefe Ayele under the active guidance and follow up of:
 * 1: Dr.Million Meshesha (PHD)
 * 2: Mr Tilahun Shiferaw(Assistant Professor)
 */
package cbr;
import jcolibri.cbraplications.StandardCBRApplication;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.CBRCase;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.CBRCaseBase;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.CBRQuery;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.Connector;
import jcolibri.exception.ExecutionException;
import jcolibri.exception.InitializingException;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.FilterBasedRetrieval.FilterConfig;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.NNConfig;
import jcolibri.connector.PlainTextConnector;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.global.Average;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Interval;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.Equal;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.similarity.local.MaxString;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.NNScoringMethod;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.selection.SelectCases;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.RetrievalResult;
import jcolibri.casebase.LinearCaseBase;
import jcolibri.method.retrieve.FilterBasedRetrieval.FilterBasedRetrievalMethod;
//import jcolibri.method.retrieve.FilterBasedRetrieval.FilterConfig;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import representation.CaseDescription;
//import representation.CaseSolution;
//import jcolibri.method.retrieve.NNretrieval.NNConfig;
import jcolibri.cbrcore.Attribute;
public class CBRApplication implements StandardCBRApplication {
private static CBRApplication _instance = null;
public static CBRApplication getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
    _instance = new CBRApplication();
    }
    return _instance;
}
CBRCaseBase _caseBase;
Connector _connector;
NNConfig simConfig;
FilterConfig filterConfig;
Collection<Attribute> hiddenAtts;
ResultDisplay resultDialog;

//******************************************************************/
// Configuration
//******************************************************************/

public void configure() throws ExecutionException {
    try {
    _connector = new PlainTextConnector();
    _connector.initFromXMLfile(jcolibri.util.FileIO.findFile("C:\\workspace11\\CBRProject\\config\\plainTextConnectorConfig.xml"));
    _caseBase = new LinearCaseBase();
    simConfig = new NNConfig();
    simConfig.setDescriptionSimFunction(new Average());
    simConfig.addMapping(
            new Attribute("CaseId", CaseDescription.class),
            new Interval(1));
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Age", CaseDescription.class), new Interval(1));
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Gender", CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Program_Type",CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Field_of_Study",CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("First_Year_First_Semester_Course_Load", CaseDescription.class), new Interval(1));
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("First_Year_First_Semester_GPA",CaseDescription.class), new Equal());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("First_Year_First_Semester_Status", CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("First_Year_Second_Semester_Course_Load", CaseDescription.class), new Interval(1));
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("First_Year_Second_Semester_GPA",CaseDescription.class), new Equal());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("First_Year_Second_Semester_Status", CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Second_Year_First_Semester_Course_Load", CaseDescription.class), new Interval(1));
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Second_Year_First_Semester_GPA",CaseDescription.class), new Equal());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute( "Second_Year_First_Semester_Status", CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Second_Year_Second_Semester_Course_Load",CaseDescription.class), new Interval(1));
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Second_Year_Second_Semester_GPA", CaseDescription.class), new Equal());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Second_Year_Second_Semester_Status", CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Third_Year_First_Semester_Course_Load", CaseDescription.class), new Interval(1));
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Third_Year_First_Semester_GPA",CaseDescription.class), new Equal());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Third_Year_First_Semester_Status", CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Third_Year_Second_Semester_Course_Load", CaseDescription.class), new Interval(1));
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Third_Year_Second_Semester_GPA",CaseDescription.class), new Equal());
    simConfig.addMapping(new Attribute("Third_Year_Second_Semester_Status", CaseDescription.class), new MaxString());
    configureConnector();
    configureCaseBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ExecutionException(e);
    }
    }       
//******************************************************************/
// Configures the connector
//******************************************************************/
private void configureConnector() throws InitializingException {
}
//******************************************************************/
// Configures the case base
//******************************************************************/
private void configureCaseBase() throws InitializingException {
_caseBase = new jcolibri.casebase.LinearCaseBase();
}
public CBRCaseBase preCycle() throws ExecutionException {
_caseBase.init(_connector);
//******************************************************************/
// Print the cases
//******************************************************************/
java.util.Collection<CBRCase> cases = _caseBase.getCases();
for (Iterator<CBRCase> it = cases.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {  
    jcolibri.cbrcore.CBRCase c = it.next();
    System.out.println(c);
    }
    return _caseBase;
    }
    public void cycle(CBRQuery query) throws ExecutionException {
//******************************************************************/
// Execute Filter
//******************************************************************/   
    Collection<CBRCase> filtered = FilterBasedRetrievalMethod.filterCases( _caseBase.getCases(), query,
    filterConfig);
//******************************************************************/
// Execute NN
//******************************************************************/   
    Collection<RetrievalResult> eval = NNScoringMethod.evaluateSimilarity( filtered, query, simConfig);
//******************************************************************/
// Select cases
//******************************************************************/       
    Collection<CBRCase> selectedCases = SelectCases.selectTopK(eval, 5);
    System.out.println("The selected Cases are...");
    for (Iterator<CBRCase> it = selectedCases.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
    jcolibri.cbrcore.CBRCase c = it.next();
    System.out.println(c);
    }
    }
    public void postCycle() throws ExecutionException {
    _connector.close();
    }
    //Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CBRApplication cbrApp = new CBRApplication();
    // cbrApp.UserSeectionGUL;
    try {
    cbrApp.configure();
    cbrApp.preCycle();
    CBRQuery query = new CBRQuery();
    CaseDescription cd = new CaseDescription();
    // CaseDescription cd = new CaseDescription();
    // cd.setCaseId(1);
    cd.setAge(22);
    cd.setGender("Female");
    cd.setProgram_Type("Regular");
    cd.setField_of_Study("English Language and Literature");
    cd.setFirst_Year_First_Semester_Course_Load(30);
    cd.setFirst_Year_First_Semester_GPA(3.04);
    cd.setFirst_Year_First_Semester_Status("Good Standing");
    cd.setFirst_Year_Second_Semester_Course_Load(30);
    cd.setFirst_Year_Second_Semester_GPA(2.71);
    cd.setFirst_Year_Second_Semester_Status("Good Standing");
    cd.setSecond_Year_First_Semester_Course_Load(30);
    cd.setSecond_Year_First_Semester_GPA(2.75);
    cd.setSecond_Year_First_Semester_Status("Good Standing");
    cd.setSecond_Year_Second_Semester_Course_Load(30);
    cd.setSecond_Year_Second_Semester_GPA(2.96);
    cd.setSecond_Year_Second_Semester_Status("Good Standing");
    cd.setThird_Year_First_Semester_Course_Load(32);
    cd.setThird_Year_First_Semester_GPA(3.21);
    cd.setThird_Year_First_Semester_Status("Good Standing");
    cd.setThird_Year_Second_Semester_Course_Load(29);
    cd.setThird_Year_Second_Semester_GPA(3.30);
    cd.setThird_Year_Second_Semester_Status("Distinction");
    query.setDescription(cd);
    cbrApp.cycle(query);
    cbrApp.postCycle();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
    }
```

While trying to use the CBRApplication.java: 
ResultDisplay resultDialog; This line in my code is also saying ResultDisplay cannot be resolved to a type: So what is the problem I made in my code that was I am trying to run Colibri Studio Eclipse Platform with this code?
How can I import the ResultDisplay package for my project?
If any one help me, I am thank full.

Comment: Looks like you are missing an `import` for `ResultDisplay `

Comment: Is ResultDisplay exist in the same package as the class above?  you might be `missing import`ing it. Can you send package of class `ResultDisplay`